# Django リレーションしたテーブルのカラムデータで検索できるようにしたい

Tags: django, 検索

Djangoでリレーションしたテーブルのカラムデータで検索できるようにしたいのですが上手くいかなくて困っています。
以下２つのテーブルがあり、TestAのリストページの検索機能でTestAのidに紐づくTestBのidのname1やname2も検索対象として検索できるようにしたいのですがうまくいきません。

```
class TestA(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, verbose_name="ID")
    bid = models.ForeignKey("TestB",on_delete=models.CASCADE,verbose_name="TestBID",)
    cid = models.ForeignKey("TestC",on_delete=models.CASCADE,verbose_name="TestCID",)
    searchvalues = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True, verbose_name="説明")


class TestB(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, verbose_name="ID")
    name1 = models.CharField(max_length=40, verbose_name="名称１")
    name2 = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name="名称２")
```

search_fieldsで検索対象を指定するらしい情報を見つけたので以下のように記述しましたがうまくいきません

```
class TestAModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    search_fields = ["id","searchvalues","bid__name1","bid__name2"]
```

どのように記述すればいいのでしょうか。